# Matching and sorting a Bukkit ChatColor expression

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm splitting up a String by spaces and then checking each piece if it contains a code (&a, &l, etc). If it matches, I have to grab the codes that are beside each other and then order them alphanumerically (0, 1, 2... a, b, c...).

Here is what I tried so far:

```
String message = "&l&aCheckpoint&m&6doreime";
String[] parts = message.split(" "); // This may not be needed for the example, but I'm only using one word for simplicity here
List<String> orderedMessage = new ArrayList<>();
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("((?:&|\u00a7)[0-9A-FK-ORa-fk-or])(.*?)"); // Completely matches the entire pattern, not what i want

for (String part : parts) {
    if (pattern.matcher(part).matches()) {
        List<String> orderedParts = new ArrayList<>();
        // what do i do?
    }
}
```

I need to change the `pattern` value so it matches groups like this:

```
Match: &l&aCheckpoint
Groups that I need: [&l, &a, Checkpoint]

Match: &m&6doreime
Groups that I need: [&m, &6, doreime]
```

How can I match each shown `Match` and split it into the 3 groups (where it splits each code section (`&[0-9A-FK-ORa-fk-or]`) and the remaining text until another code section?

**Info**: For anyone who is wondering why, when you submit color/format coded text to Minecraft, **colors have to come first**, or the format (`[a-fk-or]`) codes are ignored because of how Minecraft has parsed color codes since 1.5. By sorting them and rebuilding the message, it won't rely on users or developers getting the order correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get what you are after by using a slightly more complicated regex

```
(((?:&|§)[0-9A-FK-ORa-fk-or])+)([^&]*)
```

Breaking it down we have two important capturing groups

```
 (((?:&|§)[0-9A-FK-ORa-fk-or])+)
```

This will capture one or more code sections of and & followed by a character

```
([^&]*)
```

The second grabs any number of non & characters which will get you the remainder of that section. (This is slightly different behavior than the regex you provided - things more complicated if & is a legal character in the string.

Putting that regex into use with a Matcher you can do the following,

```
  String input = "&l&aCheckpoint&m&6doreime";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(((?:&|§)[0-9A-FK-ORa-fk-or])+)([^&]*)");
    Matcher patternMatcher = pattern.matcher(input);
    while(patternMatcher.find()){
        String[] codes = patternMatcher.group(1).split("(?=&)"); 
        String rest = patternMatcher.group(3); 
    }
```

Which will loop twice, giving you

```
  codes = ["&l", "&a"]
  rest = "Checkpoint"
```

on the first loop and the following on the second

```
  codes = ["&m", "&6"]
  rest = "doreime"
```

Comment: When you split codes using `(?=&)`, how can I split it using 1 or 2 of `&`. Ex: `&&l&&a&mCheckpoint` will show `[&, &l, &, &a, &m]` for the codes, but I want `[&&l, &&a, &m]`.

Comment: If you want to do that you can just make the character following the & optional in the main regex, ie `(((?:&|§)[0-9A-FK-ORa-fk-or]?)+)([^&]*)` 

(Note the ? after the character match)

This will make `&&l&&a&mCheckpoint ` show  

 `[&, &l, &, &a, &m], Checkpoint`

Comment: I switched the code split regex to the negative lookbehind `(?<!&)` and it achieved what I was looking for. Thanks for the help.